# Combine several flv in one video

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, flv, flash-media-server

I am recording several video on server using flash plugin and FMS (Flash Media Server). I would like to combine them into one big video which then can been played later. I am looking in to ffmpeg for solution as my requirements are to generate video via a php script. I would love to hear some options or get some guide lines.

Comment: What might help generate some answers is an attempt at the solution, and posting code so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

There is [2 different way to concatenate video file with ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files), [but only 1 work with FLV files](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-February/013441.html).

create a text file to store your flv file list, example:

```
file 'file1.flv'
file 'file2.flv'
etc...
```

so now you can use the concat demux method:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy concat.flv
```